# Exclude category from list

Tags: php, wordpress

i need to exclude a category from category list in wordpress. i have used below code.
wants to exclude category = "featured_home"

```
   $categories = get_categories();
   foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo '<button class="button" data-filter=".' .$category->name. '">'.$category->name.'</button>';
                    }
```

Please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the key of the category you want to exclude you can do this:

```
global $test; 
$categories = get_the_category($test->ID);
foreach( $categories as $key => $category ):  // add $key to foreach 
    if ($key != 5): // check if key is not the one you want to exlude
?>
<div class="blog-img <?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>">
<?php 
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

If you want to exlude category by name, just change if statement to this:

```
 if($category->cat_name != 'Category1'): ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `if`-statement to the loop:

```
foreach( $categories as $category ): 
    if ($category->cat_name === 'TheCategoryToIgnore') {
        continue; // This will skip the rest and jump to the next category
    }
    ?>
    ... // Your current code
```

If you rather check on the id or the slug, just change the condition in the `if`-statement.

Answer (score 0):

By using [wp_get_post_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/), you can specify one or more category ID's you want to exclude:

```
$categories = wp_get_post_categories($test->ID, array('exclude' => [1, 2, 3]); // It should exclude categories with ID 1, 2, and 3
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i exclude category using belowe code
$categories = get_categories();
   foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo '<button class="button" data-filter=".' .$category->name. '">'.$category->name.'</button>';
                    }

Comment: "This didn't worked for me" tells nothing about what you've tried. If you need help, you should explain what you did and what's happened.